# maximum allowed connection attempts when connecting Flutter app to aws mqtt broker

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, mqtt, flutter-dependencies, aws-iot

I'm trying to publish and subscribe to the aws mqtt broker from aws iot core. I am using [this code example](https://github.com/shamblett/mqtt_client/blob/master/example/aws_iot.dart) from the flutter [mqtt_client](https://pub.dev/packages/mqtt_client) package. I replaced all necessary placeholders to my aws specific ids, urls, ... and I have also created the certificates in aws and have them linked in my code. But when I try to connect to the broker, it tries to connect three times and after that it prints an error and disconnects. Does anybody have an idea, what the problem could be?

Here is the text, printed in the console from the second try on:

```
I/flutter ( 2969): 1-2021-10-01 10:46:16.075339 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - initiating connection try 2, auto reconnect in progress false
I/flutter ( 2969): 1-2021-10-01 10:46:16.075769 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - secure selected
I/flutter ( 2969): 1-2021-10-01 10:46:16.076389 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - calling connect
I/flutter ( 2969): 1-2021-10-01 10:46:16.076777 -- MqttSecureConnection::connect - entered
I/flutter ( 2969): 1-2021-10-01 10:46:16.216762 -- MqttSecureConnection::connect - securing socket
I/flutter ( 2969): 1-2021-10-01 10:46:16.217531 -- MqttSecureConnection::connect - start listening
I/flutter ( 2969): 1-2021-10-01 10:46:16.218088 -- MqttServerConnection::_startListening
I/flutter ( 2969): 1-2021-10-01 10:46:16.219200 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - connection complete
I/flutter ( 2969): 1-2021-10-01 10:46:16.219674 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect sending connect message
I/flutter ( 2969): 1-2021-10-01 10:46:16.220373 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::sendMessage - MQTTMessage of type MqttMessageType.connect
I/flutter ( 2969): Header: MessageType = MqttMessageType.connect, Duplicate = false, Retain = false, Qos = MqttQos.atMostOnce, Size = 22
I/flutter ( 2969): Connect Variable Header: ProtocolName=MQTT, ProtocolVersion=4, ConnectFlags=Connect Flags: Reserved1=false, CleanStart=false, WillFlag=false, WillQos=MqttQos.atMostOnce, WillRetain=false, PasswordFlag=false, UserNameFlag=false, KeepAlive=20
I/flutter ( 2969): MqttConnectPayload - client identifier is : MyIotThing
I/flutter ( 2969): 1-2021-10-01 10:46:16.224343 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - pre sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
I/flutter ( 2969): 1-2021-10-01 10:46:18.277033 -- MqttConnectionBase::_onDone - calling disconnected callback
I/flutter ( 2969): 1-2021-10-01 10:46:21.227646 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - post sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
I/flutter ( 2969): 1-2021-10-01 10:46:21.229027 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect failed
I/flutter ( 2969): MQTT client exception - mqtt-client::NoConnectionException: The maximum allowed connection attempts ({3}) were exceeded. The broker is not responding to the connection request message (Missing Connection Acknowledgement?
I/flutter ( 2969): 1-2021-10-01 10:46:21.237212 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::disconnect - entered
I/flutter ( 2969): 1-2021-10-01 10:46:21.237719 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::_performConnectionDisconnect entered
I/flutter ( 2969): 1-2021-10-01 10:46:21.240652 -- MqttConnectionKeepAlive::stop - stopping keep alive
I/flutter ( 2969): ERROR MQTT client connection failed - disconnecting, state is MqttConnectionState.disconnected
I/flutter ( 2969): Sleeping....
I/flutter ( 2969): Disconnecting
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that connect/disconnect/publish/subscribe policies are assigned to `Thing` in AWS IoT Core console.